# Configure subfolder in nginx server for Angular 5 app

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have two angular app's published to two different subfolders "testapp1" and "testapp2".

```
url's - 
    https://dev.testurl.org/foo -- For testapp1
    https://dev.testurl.org/bar -- For testapp2
```

So i build angular with basehref

```
For testapp1:
 ng build --prod --base-href /foo/ 

For testapp2:
  ng build --prod --base-href /bar/
```

My nginx configuration,

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  client_max_body_size 1000M;
  server_name dev.testurl.org localhost;

  location /testapp1/ {
            autoindex on;
    root /testapp1/dist;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /foo/index.html;    
  }
  location /testapp2/ {
            autoindex on;
    root /testapp2/dist;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /bar/index.html;    
  }
```

When i try to hit, https://dev.testurl.org/foo or /bar - it has console error says "Unexpected Syntax Error" basically it's not loading the correct sources. Any idea? whether i am building app correctly or doing something wrong nginx configuration?

Comment: Why do you have `foo` and `bar` in your question, but `testapp1` and `testapp2` in your configuration file?

Comment: @RichardSmith Edited the original post.

Comment: So `/foo/index.html` is actually located on the server at `/testapp1/dist/index.html`?

Comment: Yes you are right

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems with your configuration:

The `root` directive is used when the path to the file can be calculated by concatenating the document root with the requested URI. Otherwise, use `alias`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

The `location` directive is used to match all or part of the URI. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

For example:

```
location /foo {
    autoindex on;
    alias /testapp1/dist;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /foo/index.html;    
}
location /bar {
    autoindex on;
    alias /testapp2/dist;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /bar/index.html;    
}
```

The `location` and `alias` values should either both end with `/` or neither end with `/` in order to get the correct string substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Use alias for hosting local dist folder as subfolder as Richard said.

And ff you want to proxy pass to another endpoint as subfolder, see below thread~

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64112450/853509