# Nginx: How to rewrite url for a particular directory only

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I am using nginx for reverse proxy. I am rewriting a directory using an alias. On my alias directory, I have Angular 2 build files which are using html5 routing. So when user will refresh the page it should rewrite to the index.html present in that directory only.

"**control-pane** is overwrite by an alias"

I already tried the "try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;"
but this was referring to index.html inside main directory.

I also tried to tried to give an absolute path but still, it was not working.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xx.xxx.xx.xxx;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    location /control-panel {
        alias /var/www/html/soundoff-admin-dev/dist;
        # here rewrite should override with index.html inside "dist" directory
     }
}
```

Comment: Off the top of my head `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;` would be going to your `/` location for the index.html which would then call your proxy. So why not change the index.html path to use your location

Comment: @ShawnC. Already tried. But not working. showing 404 error on page refresh

Answer (score 0):

Borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/a/50863128/1264360

Try,

```
 location /control-panel {
    root /var/www/html/soundoff-admin-dev/dist;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /control-panel/index.html;
 }
```

Comment: I used this approach but this was not working. css & js files are overridden by index.html